# How can I add prices for objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array of objects. Model, engine, gearbox. Each facility has its name and price.

```
const ModelsTypes = [
        {
            name: "pro rs3",
            price: 100000,
        },
        {
            name: "uber rs2",
            price: 50000,
        },
        {
            name: "standard",
            price: 10000,
        },
        {
            name: "wk",
            price: 5000,
        },
    ]

const EngineTypes = [
        {
            name: "5.2l 532bhp",
            price: 10000,
        },
        {
            name: "4.2l 443bhp",
            price: 9000,
        },
        {
            name: "3.6 374bhp",
            price: 5000,
        },
        {
            name: "2.0 166bhp",
            price: 1000,
        },
    ]

const Gearbox = [
        {
            gearbox: "Manual",
            price: 5000,
        },
        {
            gearbox: "Automatic",
            price: 10000,
        },
    ]
```

The user can choose any configuration. Then all selected options are displayed in the summary. How can I add prices for each property selected by the user. Do I need another useState to sum up the price?

This is the part of the code that returns all the objects in the array.

```
{ModelsTypes.map(model =>
     <div>
      <label>{model.name}</label>
      <input onClick={addCarModel} type="radio" name="Model" value={model.name} />
     </div>
)}

{EngineTypes.map(engine =>
     <div>
      <label>{engine.name}</label>
      <input onClick={addCarEngine} type="radio" name="Model" value={engine.name} />
     </div>
)}

{Gearbox.map(gearbox =>
     <div>
      <label>{gearbox.gearbox}</label>
      <input onClick={addCarGearbox} type="radio" name="Model" value={gearbox.gearbox} />
     </div>
)}
```

Functions that components use

```
const addCarModel = (e) => {
 setCarModel(carModel => e.target.value);
}

const addCarEngine = (e) => {
 setCarEngine(carEngine => e.target.value);
}

const addCarGearbox = (e) => {
 setCarGearbox(carGearbox => e.target.value);
}
```

Summary

```
<div className={styles.summaryinfo}>
 <ul>
  <li>Model: <span>{carModel}</span></li>
  <li>Engine: <span>{carEngine}</span></li>
  <li>Gearbox: <span>{carGearbox}</span></li>
  <li>Price: <span>${totalPrice}</span></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you store all the actual objects that are selected in state, you can easily just use the `price` inside a `useEffect`

```
useEffect( () => {
  setTotalPrice( (carModel.price + carEngine.price + carGearbox.price) || 0);
},[carModel,carEngine,carGearbox])

const addCarModel = (e) => {
 setCarModel(carModel => ModelsTypes.find(x => x.name == e.target.value));
}

const addCarEngine = (e) => {
 setCarEngine(carEngine => EngineTypes.find(x => x.name == e.target.value));
}

const addCarGearbox = (e) => {
 setCarGearbox(carGearbox => Gearbox.find(x => x.gearbox == e.target.value));
}
```

Live example:

```js
const ModelsTypes=[{name:"pro rs3",price:1e5},{name:"uber rs2",price:5e4},{name:"standard",price:1e4},{name:"wk",price:5e3}],EngineTypes=[{name:"5.2l 532bhp",price:1e4},{name:"4.2l 443bhp",price:9e3},{name:"3.6 374bhp",price:5e3},{name:"2.0 166bhp",price:1e3}],Gearbox=[{gearbox:"Manual",price:5e3},{gearbox:"Automatic",price:1e4}];
    
    
const App = () => {
    const [carModel,setCarModel] = useState("");
    const [carEngine,setCarEngine] = useState("");
    const [carGearbox,setCarGearbox] = useState("");
    const [totalPrice,setTotalPrice] = useState(0);
    
    useEffect( () => {
      setTotalPrice( (carModel.price + carEngine.price + carGearbox.price) || 0);
    },[carModel,carEngine,carGearbox])

    const addCarModel = (e) => {
     setCarModel(carModel => ModelsTypes.find(x => x.name == e.target.value));
    }

    const addCarEngine = (e) => {
     setCarEngine(carEngine => EngineTypes.find(x => x.name == e.target.value));
    }

    const addCarGearbox = (e) => {
     setCarGearbox(carGearbox => Gearbox.find(x => x.gearbox == e.target.value));
    }

    return (
     <div>
        {ModelsTypes.map(model =>
             <div>
              <label>{model.name}</label>
              <input onClick={addCarModel} type="radio" name="Model" value={model.name} />
             </div>
        )}

        {EngineTypes.map(engine =>
             <div>
              <label>{engine.name}</label>
              <input onClick={addCarEngine} type="radio" name="Engine" value={engine.name} />
             </div>
        )}

        {Gearbox.map(gearbox =>
             <div>
              <label>{gearbox.gearbox}</label>
              <input onClick={addCarGearbox} type="radio" name="Gearbox" value={gearbox.gearbox} />
             </div>
        )}

        <div>
         <ul>
          <li>Model: <span>{carModel.name}</span></li>
          <li>Engine: <span>{carEngine.name}</span></li>
          <li>Gearbox: <span>{carGearbox.gearbox}</span></li>
          <li>Price: <span>${totalPrice}</span></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
   )
    
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  var {
    useReducer,
    useEffect,
    useState,
    useRef,
    useCallback
  } = React
</script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I am starting to study this code to understand it, but there was another problem. After copying it to my application and selecting a value, I get the following error.

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, price}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @Navro did you notice I had to change the rendering of the summary section? from eg `<li>Model: <span>{carModel}</span></li>` to `<li>Model: <span>{carModel.name}</span></li>`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I didn't notice it the first time. Thank you very much for help

Comment: @Navro - Glad to here Jamiec was able to provide you a working solution. Please remember to accept correct working answers by clicking the checkbox beneath them-- this provides reputation to the answerer as well as an indication to new visitors to this post that this is an answer that worked for you.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.reduce` on the selected parts to get the total price:

```
[carModel, carEngine, carGearbox].reduce((total, item)=>total + item.price,0)
```

Alternatively you could use another state variable and sum it up anytime an item is selected inside a `useEffect`:

```
const [total, setTotal] = setState(0);
useEffect(()=>{
  setTotal(carModel.price + carEngine.price + carGearbox.price)
},[carModel, carEngine, carGearbox])
```

Comment: I don't know why but when trying to add the second solution, the total contains NaN instead of the sum of its parts.